# mvaddch() doesn't print consecutive char

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a map for a videogame with lncurses in C.
I use mvaddch() to print character to the console, but when i print the same char in a row consuctivly it prints only 2 char.

```
`do {   
    for(i=0;i<ROW;i++){
        for(l=0;l<COLUMNS;l++){
            switch(map[i][l]){
                case 0:
                    mvaddch(i,l,ULCORNER);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mvaddch(i,l,URCORNER);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mvaddch(i,l,LLCORNER);
                    break;      
                case 3:
                    mvaddch(i,l,LRCORNER);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mvaddch(i,l,HLINE);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mvaddch(i,l,VLINE);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mvaddch(i,l,'a');
                    break;
                case 8:
                    mvaddch(i,l,'=');
                    break;
                default:
                    mvaddch(i,l,' ');
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
            refresh();
    } while (true);`
```

Any suggest?

Comment: Is that snippet of code in a function?  How it being called from the main() function.  What header files are included? What is the definition of `ROW`?  What is the definition of `COLUMNS`?  Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.  What are the back tics around the code for?

Comment: what is the definition of: `ULCORNER`, `URCORNER`, `LLCORNER`, `LRCORNER`, `HLINE`, and `VLINE`?

Comment: What are the contents of `map[][]`

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding: Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  Do not mix tabs and spaces when indenting

Comment: @user3629249 since it uses curses, `ULCORNER` et al. are very likely redefinitions of `ACS_ULCORNER` and related